# Finding 2D conservative normal vector fields

Tags: calculus, curves, vector-fields

Suppose I have 2 curves:

$$y=2 ± x^3$$

How would I find a 2D conservative vector field that is normal to both those curves?

I assumed that I had to parametrize each curve, but from then on I'm not sure how I would proceed.

Comment: Do you know about [orthogonal trajectories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_trajectory)?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb I do know what they are as a concept but I don't know how to find them

Comment: @NinadMunshi And that gradient is normal to both of the curves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know that the gradient of a function will always be perpendicular to its level curves? If you do then the answer becomes quick. Notice that the two curves are defined by

$$y-2\pm x^3 = 0$$

If we multiply the two together we get that

$$(y-2)^2-x^6 = 0$$

In other words $f(x,y) = (y-2)^2 - x^6$ has those curves defined as the level curves of $f(x,y) = 0$ so its gradient would satisfy the conditions.